# rxjs argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type JQueryStyleEventEmitter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I'm new to rxjs, When try to create event for incrementButton, it throw error as

```
No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
Argument of type 'Element | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown> | ArrayLike<JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown>>'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown> | ArrayLike<JQueryStyleEventEmitter<any, unknown>>'.  TS2769
```

In the below snippet Line:8 Col:35 incrementButton throw error

```js
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { fromEvent } from "rxjs";

const SimpleCounter = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState(0);

  const incrementButton = document.querySelector("incBtn");
  const increaseCount = fromEvent(incrementButton, "click");

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <h1>{result}</h1>
      <button id="incBtn">Increase</button>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

I tried type casting like below still it got failed

```js
const increaseCount = fromEvent(<JqueryStyleEventEmitter> <unknow> incrementButton, "click");
```

```js
const increaseCount = fromEvent(incrementButton as JqueryStyleEventEmitter as unknown, "click");
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 changes I have done to my code. Now it is working.

1. type conversion to querySelector using HTMLButtonElement

```js
const incrementButton = document.querySelector(
  "#incBtn"
) as HTMLButtonElement;
```

2. Moved button selection code in to the useEffect hook.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const incrementButton = document.querySelector(
    "#incBtn"
  ) as HTMLButtonElement;
  const increaseCount = fromEvent(incrementButton, "click");
  increaseCount.subscribe(() => {setResult(result++)});
});
```